# Parallel test failure using Selenium and Nunit

Tags: c#, selenium, visual-studio-2012

I have configured some tests to run in parallel using Selenium and Nunit but sometimes one of the tests kills off early and miss behaves. It's not always the same test and they are basic examples so am not sure what's happening.

I also followed the example in the following link (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=18zrtO1l7EU) to the letter but it also does not work. Sometimes one of the tests halts and doesn't continue and then fails. I've tried with both chrome and IE drivers but the same thing happens. Could this be an Nunit version issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this was because I was initially setting the Base weddriver as Static. Since taking the static off it works fine.